# Presentation software with tools

Tags: linux, presentation

I need to do a presentation from my terminal and this presentation will be followed by people in different remote locations. I am looking for a tool to assist me rather than screen sharing. I need a highlighter to mark out things when presentation to replace like a laser in reality. Any recommendation ?

Comment: whoever downvoted should explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Big Blue Button is a online conferencing tool - Open Source/Free Software, so either host your own instance or use one of the multiple hosting companies that support it.

While it has screen sharing, video and microphone, etc. it also allows the uploading of documents, which are converted to PDF on the fly and you can click through them all like a slideshow presentation.  There are also drawing tools, high lighting text tools, your mouse acts like an active laser pointer, etc.

It can even record the presentation for later viewing, although it does so by generating multiple files that are streamed at the same time.  Once you know that, easy enough to grab them as appropriate and put everything back together in one file.

Simply ignore the screen and video sharing and use the parts you need.  Works really well.  Client side simply requires Flash support, so no mobile devices.

Comment: Great, thanks for this recommendation, seems very good for presentation, on top it's open source, i'll try that !!

Answer (score 0):

Noor
You can check out also Visme software https://www.visme.co/presentation-software/ , they have also online presentation maker. In case you want your presentation to make more attractive and keep people engaged, I recommend you to Tumli templates https://tumli.net/journal/powerpoint-infographic-template , I've been cooperating with them for half a tear and i really appreciate their work

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want screen sharing software which can do highlighting.

1. [Team Viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/). Features video [here](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/features/).